# Socat forwarder over a single secure connection

Tags: ssl, port, forwarding, socat

I'd like to create a port forwarder with socat so that multiple forked connections are redirected over a single openssl channel. Can I do that in socat without using any tun or vpn?

So far I have established a secure connection (e.g., with socat)

SERVER:

```
socat openssl-listen:MYPORT,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=client.crt echo
```

CLIENT:

```
socat stdio openssl-connect:MYSERVERIP:MYPORT,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt,sourceport=4444
```

and then I create a port forwarder at the ssl client with socat:

```
socat  -lmlocal2 TCP4-LISTEN:5555,fork TCP4:localhost:4444
```

But with this configuration I can only establish a single connection to MYSERVERIP:MYPORT via the ssl client (port 5555).

I want only a single outgoing connection, so I do not want to fork a new ssl connection every time I accept like so:

```
socat -lmlocal2 TCP4-LISTEN:5555,fork openssl-connect:MYSERVERIP:MYPORT
```

Any advice?

Comment: Good question. I just asked a very similar one here, involving tunneling over `ssh` instead of openssl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924244/multiplexing-a-tcp-connection-through-a-dumb-shell-connection

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this will not be possible with socat. socat addresses (both sides) are linked, once the connection to one side is closed the other side is also closed.